# Install brexis / laravel-workflow issue

Tags: php, laravel, package, workflow

I'm trying to install a workflow package in Laravel `brexis / laravel-workflow` but i got some error.
I also tried to install another package `zerodahero/laravel-workflow` which is the same thing and It says is for laravel 7 but still has the same error.
my Laravel version is 7 and php 7.3 running laravel homestead vagrant.

```
Problem 1
- Conclusion: don't install brexis/laravel-workflow 1.3.3
- Conclusion: don't install brexis/laravel-workflow 1.3.2
- Conclusion: don't install brexis/laravel-workflow 1.3.1
- Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v7.9.2
- Installation request for brexis/laravel-workflow ^1.3 -> satisfiable by brexis/laravel-workflow[1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.3.3].
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- brexis/laravel-workflow 1.3.0 requires illuminate/console 5.3.* || 5.4.* || 5.5.* || 5.6.* || 5.7.* || 5.8.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[5.3.x-dev, 5.4.x-dev, 5.5.x-dev, 5.6.x-dev, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev], illuminate/console[5.3.x-dev, 5.4.x-dev, 5.5.x-dev, 5.6.x-dev, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev, v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9, v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9].
- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[5.3.x-dev, v7.9.2].
- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[5.4.x-dev, v7.9.2].
- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[5.5.x-dev, v7.9.2].
- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[5.6.x-dev, v7.9.2].
- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[5.7.x-dev, v7.9.2].
- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[5.8.x-dev, v7.9.2].
- don't install illuminate/console 5.7.17|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console 5.7.18|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console 5.7.19|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console 5.7.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.7.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.7.1|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.7.10|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.7.11|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.7.15|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.7.2|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.7.20|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.7.21|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.7.22|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.7.23|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.7.26|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.7.27|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.7.28|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.7.3|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.7.4|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.7.5|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.7.6|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.7.7|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.7.8|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.7.9|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console 5.8.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.8.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.8.11|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.8.12|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.8.14|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.8.15|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.8.17|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.8.18|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.8.19|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.8.2|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.8.20|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.8.22|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.8.24|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.8.27|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.8.28|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.8.29|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.8.3|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.8.30|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.8.31|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.8.32|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.8.33|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.8.34|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.8.35|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.8.36|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.8.4|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.8.8|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.8.9|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console 5.3.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console 5.4.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console 5.5.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console 5.6.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.3.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.3.16|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.3.23|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.3.4|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.4.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.4.13|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.4.17|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.4.19|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.4.27|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.4.36|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.4.9|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.5.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.5.16|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.5.17|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.5.2|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.5.28|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.5.33|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.5.34|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.5.35|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.5.36|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.5.37|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.5.39|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.5.40|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.5.41|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.5.43|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.5.44|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.6.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.6.1|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.6.10|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.6.11|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.6.12|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.6.13|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.6.14|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.6.15|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.6.16|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.6.17|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.6.19|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.6.2|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.6.20|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.6.21|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.6.22|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.6.23|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.6.24|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.6.26|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.6.27|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.6.28|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.6.29|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.6.3|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.6.30|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.6.31|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.6.32|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.6.33|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.6.34|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.6.35|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.6.36|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.6.37|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.6.38|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.6.39|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.6.4|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.6.5|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.6.6|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.6.7|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.6.8|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/console v5.6.9|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v7.9.2, required as ^7.0) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v7.9.2].
```

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

and my package.json file is:

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"type": "project",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": [
    "framework",
    "laravel"
],
"license": "MIT",
"require": {
    "php": "^7.2.5",
    "alexpechkarev/geometry-library": "1.0",
    "apility/laravel-fcm": "^1.4",
    "brexis/laravel-workflow": "^1.3",
    "darkaonline/l5-swagger": "^7.0",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
    "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^1.0",
    "grimzy/laravel-mysql-spatial": "^2.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
    "hekmatinasser/verta": "^1.10",
    "jedrzej/pimpable": "0.0.6",
    "kavenegar/laravel": "^1.2",
    "laravel/framework": "^7.0",
    "laravel/passport": "^8.4",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
    "laravel/ui": "^2.0",
    "rap2hpoutre/fast-excel": "^1.7",
    "spatie/laravel-permission": "^3.11",
    "zerodahero/laravel-workflow": "^3.1",
    "zircote/swagger-php": "^3.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "facade/ignition": "^2.0",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.9.1",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.3.1",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^4.1",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.5"
},
"config": {
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true
},
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "dont-discover": []
    }
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
"scripts": {
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
    ],
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
    ]
},
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/sebdesign/state-machine"
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/zerodahero/laravel-workflow should work because it supports laravel 7, however, from composer.json I do see you have both packages included there, you need to remove brexis/laravel-workflow from you composer.json, then delete the file composer.lock and run `composer install` again